# How to properly unsubscribe to an onValue listener for Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Background: This is a practice todo list app where I'm using onValue to listen to changes to the list of todos in realtime database, and then mapping that onto a tasks array in the front end.

I previously had a memory leak error appear when using onValue in the following manner - when I didn't unsubscribe from my onValue listener:

```
  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (user) {

    onValue(ref(database, `users/${user}/tasks`), (snapshot) => {
      const todos = snapshot.val();

      const tasks = [];

      for (let id in todos) {
        tasks.push({ ...todos[id], id: id })
      }

      setTasks(tasks)
    })
    
  } else {
    setTasks([])
  }
}, [user])
```

I saw from some other questions here that onValue returns an unsubscribe function, and I also saw an answer that by adding return to the onValue line, I could unsubscribe from it - I've tried to do this below:

```
 useEffect(
    () => {
      if (user) {

        return onValue(ref(database, `users/${user}/tasks`), (snapshot) => {
          const todos = snapshot.val();

          const tasks = [];

          for (let id in todos) {
            tasks.push({ ...todos[id], id: id })
          }

          setTasks(tasks)
        })
        
      } else {
        setTasks([])
      }
    }, [user])
```

It seems to work for me, but could I get some help to confirm that this is the proper way to unsubscribe from this onValue listener?

Comment: I answered below, but note that in general Stack Overflow works better when you post a problem instead of a "please verify that this code that seems to work is indeed correct".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `useEffect` callback needs to return an unsubscribe function, so that React can call that when the component/hook is no longer needed. By returning the return value from `onValue`, you ensure that the `onValue` gets unsubscribed when the component/hook is no longer needed. If that is what you want to accomplish (which seems the case), then this indeed looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

With Web v9, the result of an `onValue()` call is the **'unsubscriber'**.

```js
const unsubscribe = onValue(ref(database, `sessions/${session}`), (snapshot) => {
    const sessionData= snapshot.val();
    if( sessionData.status === 'over' )
    {
         // remove the listener
         unsubscribe();
    }else{

         // Do something with the snapshot data 
    }

})
```

Edit : While this information is  unfortunately omitted from firebase documentation, the firebase api reference of onValue clearly shows that it returns Unsubscriber https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#onvalue

> onValue()
> Returns:
> **Unsubscribe**
> A function that can be invoked to remove the listener.

Comment: Kindly provide reference of your answer from documentaion.

Thanks